# What is the fastest way to complete a list of tasks with node.js async?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I have an array of fs.writeFile png jobs with the png headers already removed like so

```
canvas.toDataURL().replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/,"")
```

jobs array like this

```
jobs=[['location0/file0'],['location1/file1'],['location2/file2'],['location3/file3']];
```

I have just started to use async and was looking at their docs and there are lots of methods

queue looks interesting and parallel..

Right now I handle my jobs (in a async.waterfall) like so

```
    function(callback){//part of waterfall
        (function fswritefile(){
            if(jobs.length!==0){
                var job=jobs.shift();
                fs.writeFile(job[0],(new Buffer(job[1],'base64')),function(e){if(e){console.log(e);}else{fswritefile();}})
                }
            else{callback();}
            })();
        },//end of waterfall part
```

Could this be done more efficiently/faster using this module?

Comment: For instances such as these look up design patterns and control flows for the language, they are a big help! Try full parallel here : http://book.mixu.net/node/ch7.html

Comment: Unrelated, but can I ask why you create and immediately call the closure `fswritefile`? It shouldn't be necessary..

Comment: @nickclaw fswritefile asks if the array is not empty, if it is not then it shifts the job (shortening the array) and uses it to write the file. The callback is again fswritefile this happens until the jobs array has no items and else is true which means the task on all is complete!

Comment: Why would you say it's not necessary?

Comment: Oh whoops. I didn't scroll far enough to the right to see that you're calling it recursively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`async.waterfall` will process jobs sequentially. I think you could do everything in parallel with [async.each](https://github.com/caolan/async#eacharr-iterator-callback):

```
async.each(jobs, function (job, done) {
   var data = new Buffer(job[1],'base64');
   fs.writeFile(job[0], data, done);
}, function (err) {
  // …
});
```

All jobs will start everything in parallel. However, node.js always limits the number of concurrent operations on the disk to 4.

**EDIT**: No matter what you do, node.js will limit the number of concurrent operations on the fs. The main reason is that you have only have 1 disk and it would be inefficient to attempt more.

Comment: 4? Ok, wont that mean that async tries to perform all tasks at once but can't?

Comment: By can't - I mean, if there were more than 4 jobs

Comment: Async will immediately attempts to start all jobs. Since node will only allow 4 operations, the rest will wait until a spot frees up.

Comment: I just tested your code with a timer. Yours takes longer it seems. Yours is 100ms slower than my original somehow? var start=(+new Date());var end=((+new Date())-start); I expected yours to be 4x faster as my code  is doing one file at at time whereas yours should be doing 4 at a time

Comment: I'm on a vps, would that make a difference?

Comment: possibly… can you add logs to see when the jobs start. You can also try eachSeries, which lets you define the concurrency that async will use.